# Enabling multiple checkout tfs midstream?

Tags: tfs

Can multiple checkout be enabled within tfs at any time?  Does everyone need to check in their files before this switch should be made, or does this even matter?  I know we can enable it midstream, I just don't know what the side effects might be if people have files checked out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The setting is server side so if you change it and someone has already checked out a file, it won't make any difference to them.  However, they might get a surprise when they come to check-in and find out they have conflicts for the first time.

Bear in mind that if anyone is using a Local Workspace today, the setting won't apply to them anyway as the server doesn't know they are editing the file until they check-in.